# Port redirection from 8080 to 80 for a specific domain

Tags: centos, vps, iptables

As I have redirected incoming domains from domain.com:80 to domain.com:8080 using the command for iptables as follows

`sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

All the domains I have, are redirected from port 80 to 8080 by default, but I dont want this to happen this for a specific domain. For example, I dont want myDomain.com to be redirected to port 8080 from 80.

I want to do it using the iptables only!

Answer (score 0):

Bad news, you cannot.

IP Tables works at transport layer (TCP in this case) which equates to layer 4 of the OSI 7 layer model:

[image: The OSI 7 level]

HTTP domains are described by layers 5 to 6, over which IP tables has no visibility.

M.